# Code problem in Javascript to Print Multiplication Table

Tags: javascript, html, printing, user-input

Code problem in Javascript while trying to print a multiplication table. I am trying to code a program, that takes two inputs from the user. One will be for the multiplication table which he wants, i.e., if he gives 2, then the multiplication table of 2 will ve displayed. The other input shall be the number up to which the number should be printed. So, if the person gives 5 as the input, then multiplication table f 2, up to times 5 shall be printed by the program. But for some reason, it isn't working. Please advise me on what I should do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Print Multiplication Table using Javascript</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#6030A8">
<p> Please enter the number for which you want to see the multiplication table: <input type="number" id="multi"></input></p>
 Please enter the number till much you would like your number to be multiplied: <input type="number" id="limit"></input></p>

<p> To get your answer, please click the button below: </p> <br>

<button onclick="function1()">Your_Result</button>

<p id = "ans"></p>

<script>
var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("multi").innerHTML.value);
var B = parseInt(document.getElementById("limit").innerHTML.value);

function function1()
{
    var i;
 for  (i=1; i<B; i++) {
     document.getElementbyId("ans").innerHTML = "A*i";
 }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.innerHTML.value` ..? `input` element doesn't have `innerHTML` property. `.innerHTML = "A*i"` won't work either, drop the quotes around the value expression, and concatenate the string before setting it to `innerHTML`, currently you're overriding the value on every round of the loop, and the last value is what you'll see (when fixing the other problems).

Comment: Also a typo in `getElementbyId` inside the loop.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the problems where I have gone wrong. If you know what I have done wrong, Please make corrections in the code and explain.